# Why my cassandra table got empty without any user action?

Tags: database, cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with 4 nodes. Data is stored with a replication factor of 3. One morning, couple of my tables had no data in it. It used to have around 500 entries and all of a sudden it vanished.

I have checked all possible ways in which data could be lost.

1. I checked application logs but no delete operation was fired from the application.
2. I checked SSH logs but no unauthorised access has bgeen made to the DB servers.

I cant find any clue why this could happen. Can anybody suggest me a possible reason?

**Pls find table definition below**

```
CREATE TABLE test.users (
    id text,
    userid text,  
    updatetime timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, userid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (userid ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: To help us, can you check your data directory for this specific table? Can you still see the sstable files?

Comment: Yes i can see the files. But i flushed using nodetool. So are those files of much use now?

Comment: Ok, good news, chances are you can recover your data (if that's your objective). Did you check your Cassandra logs to find relevant error messages? Those data files should be loaded, maybe they are corrupted. You may want to try to restart your cluster (one node at a time to avoid outages) and check carefully your Cassandra logs.
Ah, yea, flushing with nodetool shouldn't be a problem at all and is not the root cause of your issue.

Comment: i wanted to find the cause as it may occur in future on some critical data

Comment: Did you scan through your logs to see potential error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Did you [insert with a TTL](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_using/useTTL.html)? More generally, what statements did you use to insert the data?

Comment: No i didnt insert it with TTL. I use simple insert statement (from java) without any TTL or timestamps. Moreover, data has been inserted over a period of time so any pre configured TTL (if it existed) couldn't expire for all rows together

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check `default_time_to_live` option in table definition. Can you also share your table definition?  Check if you have any SSTables on the disk for that table across your nodes in your C* cluster.

Comment: I have added my table definition to the original question. Also, the data has been added over a period of time and not at once. So TTL should not apply to all of them at the same instant right?